# Multiple select statements giving wrong output in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a multiple select statement query as below,

```
select Date(Transactiondate),
(Select count(*) from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where vehiclecatcode='cat1' and transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01') as LMV,
(Select count(*)  from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where vehiclecatcode='cat2' and transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' ) as LCV,
(Select count(*)  from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where vehiclecatcode='cat3' and transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' ) as Truck,
(Select count(*)  from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where vehiclecatcode='cat4' and transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' ) as Bus,
(Select count(*)  from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where vehiclecatcode='cat5' and transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' ) as MAV,
(Select count(*)  from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where vehiclecatcode='cat6' and transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' ) as MAV6
from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans where transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' group by date(transactiondate);
```

but this is giving very wrong output as for all dates it is calculating the same number like below

```
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
2018-05-17  292 628 1317    165 1423    9
```

could somebody please help me where i am doing mistake in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select Date(Transactiondate),
  sum(vehiclecatcode='cat1') as LMV,
  sum(vehiclecatcode='cat2') as LCV,
  sum(vehiclecatcode='cat3') as Truck,
  sum(vehiclecatcode='cat4') as Bus,
  sum(vehiclecatcode='cat5') as MAV,
  sum(vehiclecatcode='cat6') as MAV6
from tms_plaza.tms_lanetrans 
where transactiondate >= '2018-05-01' and transactiondate <= '2018-07-01' 
group by date(transactiondate);
```

Comment: it worked like charm forpas.. thank you so much.. appreciate your earliest response

Comment: btw what could it make difference between sum and count. kindly clarify

Comment: The way to do it in standard SQL is with COUNT like this: `COUNT(CASE WHEN vehiclecatcode='cat1' THEN 1 END` or with SUM(CASE WHEN vehiclecatcode='cat1' THEN 1 END). In both cases the result is the same, because counting 1s is the same as summing them. The use of SUM() like in my query is just a MySql feature because any expression like `vehiclecatcode='cat1'` is evaluated as 1 for true or 0 for false.